# what is the maximum length of the mail body?

Tags: asp-classic

I want to send a mail but it gives me a the following error

> Paragraph is too large

i want to know that what is the maximum length of a mail while sending in asp vbscript

Answer (score 1):

Seems other people have had the [same problem](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=7983&lngWId=4). From the linked page:

> I discovered that ASPMail was returning an odd message "paragraph too large"...
>   I found that messages about 123,000 bytes or so would cause this to occur.

A comment at the bottom of the page suggests a workaround:

> Turns out "Paragraph is too large" it is not because the page size is too big. It's because the string of text is going on too long and the line is too wide. Add a "VBCrLf" every now and then and your set. Whew.

Comment: all the text is come from the database

Answer (score 0):

I think this mostly depends on your server settings, and when using an smtp server it probably depends on its settings aswell.